# How to make the result to be show in a new line in C

Tags: c

I have 1 question how to make on the code below , after I enter a number for example 56 to show like that:
56
TEXT
Because right now it is 56TEXT.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int sum = 0;                         
    int a;                                
    for (a = 0; a <= 22; a++){          
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    printf ("Summe von 22: %i\n ",sum); 

    int i;
    while (i) {
        int i = 0;
        int b;

        printf ("THE NUMBER HERE ;" );
        scanf ("%i",&b);
        printf ("%i",b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You knew how to do it in the first `printf()`, why didn't you do the same thing in the last `printf()`?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print a newline after the number:

```
printf ("%i\n", b);
```